# REST calls from Chrome and Firefox browsers don't add cookie/sessionid details to the request when the page is cached with 'Manifest'

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, manifest

**Background:**

I am building an offline application that should be able to communicate with the REST services at the server when user clicks on a 'SYNC' button. The first time when the user access the application there will be net connectivity and then they can go offline and work with the app in their browser. The data collected from the user when they are offline will be stored in POUCHDB.

The application should load its page even when there is no connectivity to reach the server. To store my application into the browser i have a manifest file which is attached to the 'index.html' page.

**Issue:**

The REST service at the server expects a cookie/sessionid passed to the server while making a REST call from the client to the server. The rest calls made from the client is not adding the session id/cookie name to the request . This issue happens only in Firefox and Chrome, it works fine in IE11.

The moment i remove the manifest details from the 'index.html' page then everythig is fine ( the session id/cookie details are included with the request).

**REST Request http header when there is manifest file used in the page:**

```
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:7101/ERS/online/v1/views/?statusCode=published
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:7101/EOffline/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
```

**REST Request http header when there is no manifest file used in the page:**

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:7101
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:7101/ERS/online/v1/instances/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=esc1XeWczQvYkyPmgHffCVfYI1jU_BMF1C7SByrgWL0-_ZgVDVNM!-1045045782
Host:127.0.0.1:7101
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:7101/EOffline/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Fri, 20 Mar 2015 04:08:23 GMT
EformsDA:MadeByDA
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID:296e7550-171d-457b-a020-dd4eae786e1e-00000186
```

**offline.manifest**

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2015-07-01 v1.0.0

/controllers/offlineController.js
/controllers/offlineMainController.js
```

**index.html page**

```
<html ng-app="app" lang="en" manifest="offline.manifest" type="text/cache-manifest">
</html>
```

Any clue whats going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue that was causing this weired behaviour. 
When i was using the manifest file to cache  the page locally, the browser was attempting to fetch even the REST service data from local (not attempting to fetch the data from the server by issuing a REST call pointing to the server).

All I had to do was modify my 'manifest' file to fetch the rest service data from the NETWORK, not from the cache.

```
NETWORK:
/ERS/online/v1/views/?statusCode=published
/ERS/online/v1/instances/
/ERS/online/v1/instance/ 
/ERS/online/v1/view/
/ERS/online/v1/refdata/
```